# Static cells with an array

Tags: mysql, ios

I'm using xml to export mysql information to ios, and that saves it in an array. However, I have static cells for my table. How would I be able to call a string from the array, seeing as how I cannot use objectForIndex....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use objectAtIndex: to populate a static cell with data. In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you usually return the static cell via its IBOutlet, but there's no reason you can't set a value for a label (or any other UI element) in that static cell before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the docs for `NSArray` will show you that the name of the method is not `objectForIndex:`, it's `objectAtIndex:`. Learning to use the reference docs will save you countless hours of time.

BTW - your last few questions have all been tagged as Xcode and core-data. Why? None of them have anything to do with the things.

FYI - this is meant to be helpful advice, not any kind of negative comment. :)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the feedback. Whoops, I forgot to include that this is on Xcode. I will make sure to include that in my questions.

Comment: Only add Xcode if the question is actually about using Xcode. Your questions have been about Objective-C and iOS, not Xcode. If you have a question about how to use some aspect of Xcode, then add the Xcode tag. If your question is about your code, don't use the Xcode tag.